# Replace get_header template from plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Im creating a plugin what overrides templates which included in plugin folder. First of all Im trying to override header.php and footer.php files. Tried to create various solutions, but any of them doesnt work. ([This is one of the plugin solutions](https://docs.appthemes.com/tutorials/creating-grandchild-themes/))
Tried to remove `get_header` hook and add like new, but this doesnt help.

There is some of the latest solutions, what I tried

```
function header_override () {
    // $template = locate_template('header.php');

    // load_template(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/header.php');
    // print_r($template);

    if ( $overridden_template = locate_template( 'header.php' ) ) {
        load_template( $overridden_template );
    }else{
        load_template(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/header.php');
    }
}
add_action('template_include', 'header_override');


function new_header_output() {
    remove_action( 'get_header', 'header_output', 20);
    load_template(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/header.php');
}
add_action('get_header', 'new_header_output');


function action_function_name_391( $name, $args ){
    print_r("custom header");
}
add_action( 'get_header', 'action_function_name_391', 10, 2 );
```

Maybe someone has a similar problem to override theme templates

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you are doing. Is this a plugin that you want to use across all possible themes, or just ones that you can control? The function `get_header()` is a core function, and it intentionally uses `do_action` instead of `apply_filters`. The former is used for "here's what's going to happen" and the latter is used for "does anyone have an opinion on this". So WordPress clearly doesn't anyone jumping in at this stage. Your only option, I think, is to jump in _before_ with the `template_include` filter where you _can_ change the final file.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Im gonna use this plugin for my themes. And how I can do that?

Comment: If you control the themes, then don't call `get_header`, change it to something else like `get_custom_header` that you define in your plugin

Comment: @ChrisHaas I have a workflow with multiple sites with one theme, with updates. And I need exactly the plugin solution, because not in every page it will be

Comment: I'd then look into `template_include`. That filter is called on every non-admin page and you can do what you need there. One word of note, WordPress has several functions and hooks with the word "template" in it and they don't always mean the same thing. `template` include is the hook used to determine if, for instance `index.php` or `page.php` should be used. `get_header` doesn't call that hook, however, and instead the functions `locate_template` and `load_template` get called, none of which use any filters.

Answer (score 2):

```
add_action('get_header', 'replace_header');
 function replace_header(){
require PLUGIN_DIR.'includes/templates/header.php';

$templates   = [];
$templates[] = 'header.php';
remove_all_actions( 'wp_head' );
ob_start();
locate_template( $templates, true );
ob_get_clean();
```

}